# How to exclude specific directories for dist-gzip / dist-zip?

Tags: automake

**Background**:
Automake provides different [types of distributions](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/The-Types-of-Distributions.html). After reading the docs "[What Goes in a Distribution](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/automake-1.6.1/html_chapter/automake_15.html)" I know how to *include* extra directories *in general*. But I'm not sure about the best way to *exclude* directories in this list *for a single rule*.

This is the part in current `configure.ac` that adds to the dist directories

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build_aux])
```

And this is the part in current `Makefile.am` that adds to the dist directories

```
SUBDIRS = sources po doc tests
EXTRA_DIST = build_windows
```

Furthermore `Makefile.am` has

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = dist-zip
```

For enabling the zip distribution.

**Result**: both `package.tar.gz` and `package.zip` have the same content. Therefore the following directories are included:

- build_aux
- build_windows
- doc
- m4
- po
- sources
- tests

**Question**:
How to **exclude** `build_windows` in `package.tar.gz` and `m4` in `package.zip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer:

> Different types of distributions only mean different format, but the content of these is designed to be exactly the same.

Therefore the solution for the goal is:

- remove `build_windows` from `EXTRA_DIST` for having only needed content in the tar.gz distribution
- remove `dist-zip` from `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS` to prevent auto-generation of package.zip
- add (or in this case edit) the `dist-hook` rule to manually:

  - check if `build_windows` exist (it won't exist if build from `package.tar.gz`)
  - copy the dist-content to a temporary directory
  - remove/add files/folders there as needed
  - create a `package_win.zip` from this folder (use a different name for preventing a possible `package.zip` to overwrite the file)

Edit: **removing anything from the manually created dist folder will break `make dist`** (or at least `make distcheck`), therefore this is only a good idea if you want to remove everything that has to do with autoconf/automake/Makfiles in general

Answer (score 1):

The short version is you don't. Different types of distributions only mean different format, but the content of these is designed to be exactly the same.